# Grouping Blogger posts for blogs monitored via Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, grouping, blogger

I'm trying to exploit the **content grouping** feature provided by **Google Analytics** for a blog hosted by **Google Blogger**.

The blog has been correctly set to be monitored by using Google Analytics (GA). GA provides 3 ways of grouping but in my case only the **grouping by tracking code** option seems to be the correct one. As far as I can see inspecting a blog page, by putting into the template the GA include

```
<b:include data='blog' name='google-analytics'/>
```

I correctly get the following JavaScript ga.js snippet into the page

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XXXXXXXXXXX']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ?
              'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

The problem is that I've no way to add the required call to set the group as required.

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-40265412-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_setPageGroup', 1, 'My Group Name']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Any idea in which way this can be implemented?

Thanks in advance

Comment: go to the template editor and add the code manually?